# AS3 : EventListener won't be removed in an [IF]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, actionscript, listener

I have searched how to pass arguments through EventListeners, and I used the method without calling an anonymous function to remove the EventListener later.

The issue is that the EventListener will be removed if out the IF function, but not if it is in the IF function.
How could I do that ?

The code :

```
function dragShip(m:MouseEvent):void
{
    var func:Function = dispositionShip(m.target);

    if (isDragging == false)
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, func);
        m.target.startDrag(true);
        isDragging = true;
    }
      else
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, func);
        isDragging = false;
        placeShip(m.target , mouseX , mouseY , m.target.rotation);
    }
    // if the EventListener is put here, it gets removed, but not if put just in the else
}
```

**NOTE** : `dispositionShip()`returns a **function**.

Edit : Here is the following part of the code :

```
function dispositionShip(shipTarg):Function
{
    return function(k:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        rotateShip(k,shipTarg);
    };
}

function rotateShip(k:KeyboardEvent,ship:Object):void
{
    if (k.keyCode == 39)
    {
        ship.rotation += 90;
    } 
    else if (k.keyCode == 37)
    {
        ship.rotation -= 90;
    } 
}
```

Moreover, if I replace `rotateShip(k,shipTarg);` by a simple `trace`, it also does not work.

Comment: You are doing a great mistake. `var func:Function = dispositionShip(m.target);` - you are actually **calling** the function this way. If it does not return a function by it's own, the listener won't work properly!

Comment: Is dispositionShip creating a functioneach time is called? or returning one from a Dictionary or is a mistake(you called the function by mistake and you intended to get a partial function

Comment: Yes it calls the function `dispositionShip()`, but the function returns a function.
See edit above.

Comment: Quite a curious setup and probably at the origin of your problem. It does not remove the correct method.

Comment: can you show the body of dispositionShip function? It looks like it returns different function each time that is why it is not removed in the else part (which I'm sure is called later) and it works outside (which is called immediately after registering event - thus with the same function).

Comment: I edited my post, thanks for answers though !
@BotMaster I took the structure out of there : http://tinyurl.com/kdl3kgl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you call

```
function dispositionShip(shipTarg):Function
{
    return function(k:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        rotateShip(k,shipTarg);
    };
}
```

You're creating a new anonymous `Object` of type `Function` that calls `rotateShip()`, so when you call `stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, func);` your `func` is a different `Object` to the `func` you passed into `addEventListener()`, so it doesn't match the orginal listener and doesn't get removed.

A better way to do this would be to store the current mouse target in a member `var`. IE:

```
var currentShip:Object;
function dragShip(m:MouseEvent):void
{   
    if (isDragging == false)
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPress);
        m.target.startDrag(true);
        isDragging = true;
        currentShip = m.target;
    }
      else
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPress);
        isDragging = false;
        placeShip(m.target , mouseX , mouseY , m.target.rotation);
        currentShip = null;
    }
}
function keyPress(k:KeyboardEvent):void
{
     rotateShip(k,currentShip); 
}
```